# AWS GraphQL JSON string formatting

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-web-services

I'm attempting to create an object value to pass into DynamoDB using AWS AppSync and GraphQL. I'm very close to what I need but I'm stumbling on nested JSON.

Let's say I have an array:

```
let officers = [{"id":"0","IgRole":"Role1","IgName":"testname1","IgEmail":"testemail1","IgPhone":"testphone1","IgStart":"teststart1","IgEnd":"testend1"},
                {"id":"1","IgRole":"Role2","IgName":"testname2","IgEmail":"testemail2","IgPhone":"testphone2","IgStart":"teststart2","IgEnd":"testend2"}]
```

I now want to create an object with each of the array values as a child object so, I do this:

```
for (let i in officers) {
      officersJson['"' + officers[i].IgRole + '"'] = '{"Name":"' + officers[i].IgName + '","Email":"' + officers[i].IgEmail + '","Phone":"' + officers[i].IgPhone + '","Date commenced":"' + officers[i].IgStart + '","Date to end":"' + officers[i].IgEnd + '"}';
    }
```

Here are the results:

```
Object {
    "Role1": "{'Name':'testname1','Email':'testemail1','Phone':'testphone1','Date commenced':'teststart1','Date to end':'testend1'}",
    "Role2": "{'Name':'testname2','Email':'testemail2','Phone':'testphone2','Date commenced':'teststart2','Date to end':'testend2'}"
}
```

I think the problem is that the each entire key / value is not in string format. If you look at
`"Role1": "{......`
you can see that the string breaks.

and this is the response from AWS:

```
Variable 'Officers' has an invalid value. Unable to parse {\"Role1\"={\"Nam
```

See the = sign

How can I format the object into a complete JSON string? I was fairly pleased I managed to get anywhere near the format I needed but this last bit has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked it out. I needed a slightly different approach. Posting it in case it helps anyone else:

Firstly I created an array of roles, as this will be the keys for the value objects:

```
for (let i in officers) {
      roles.push(officers[i].IgRole);
    }
```

I then created a new array.

```
let arrOfficers = [];

for (let i in officers) {
      arrOfficers.push(officers[i]);
    }
```

I then use a function to create objects from an array:

```
 function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
      return objectArray.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
        let key = obj[property];
        if (!acc[key]) {
          acc[key] = [];
        }
        acc[key].push(obj);
        return acc;
      }, {});
    }

    let newresult = groupBy(arrOfficers, "IgRole");
```

Finally I create my object and then stringify it:

```
 let officersJson = {};

    for (let i in roles) {
       officersJson[roles[i]] = newresult[roles[i]][0];
    }

theObjectIwant = JSON.stringify(officersJson)
```